# You are supposed to have gone to school. / You were supposed to go to school

Tags: meaning

> 1 You are supposed to have gone to school.
>
> 2 You were supposed to go to school.

These two mean almost the same. But 1, I reckon, means that going to school is still a pressing matter. In 2 having gone to school is not important now.

Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. You are supposed to have gone to school.

> 2. You were supposed to go to school.

In #1, the expectations in #2 remain true.  There are additional requirements: The person not only is supposed to go to school, he is supposed to have gone by now.  There is a sense of urgency.